# Making logger to show log messages of level INFO..logging is of package level

Tags: java, log4j

After a lot a search I finally got to know that we can log only a specific level message (for eg. in my case only INFO message) using LevelMatchFilter in log4j.xml file ...

here is the code ..

```
<filter type="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
  <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
  <levelToMatch  value="INFO" />
</filter>
<filter type="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter" />
```

My scenario is I have some packages like..

```
1)com.test.servlet
2)com.test.service
3)com.test.filter
4)com.test.model
```

Now what my requirement is ..

```
1) servlet package should print loggers from DEBUG level and above.
2) service package should print loggers from ERROR level and above.
3) rest of the package should print only INFO log messages.
```

I got code for the 3rd point but i am clueless on how to apply it a specific package.

Someone guide on achieving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your `log4j.xml` and check.

```
<logger name="com.test.servlet" additivity="false">
  <level value="debug"/> 
</logger>
<logger name="com.test.service" additivity="false">
  <level value="error"/> 
</logger>
<logger name="com.test.filter" additivity="false">
  <level value="info"/> 
</logger>
<logger name="com.test.model" additivity="false">
  <level value="info"/> 
</logger>
```

Refer [Log4jXmlFormat](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) for more details.